# What are the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[This article](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/cyclic/cyclic.pdf) says that the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are the elements which are prime with respect to $n$.

For instance, the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ would be $\{\overline0,\overline1,\overline2,\overline3,\overline4,\overline5,\overline6\}$.

Why can $\overline1$ and $\overline0$ not generate the whole group? $\overline1+\overline1=\overline{1+1}=\overline2$, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\bar 0$ is never a generator of $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: What generates $\overline0$ then?

Comment: The subgroup $\{\bar 0\}$ of $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: Sorry I guess adding $\overline1$ $n$ times does.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you can not say "adding $\bar 1$ n times generates something". Yes, $\underset{n}{\underbrace{\bar 1 + \dots + \bar 1}} = 0$, but $\bar 1$ (more precisely the singleton $\{\bar 1 \}$) generates a larger subgroup than just $\{\bar 0\}$ (in fact, it generates $\mathbb Z_n$ entirely).

Comment: @Ayush: Just by the way, the subscript should go outside the `\mathbb` font. Compare `\mathbb{Z_n}` which produces
$$\Huge\mathbb{Z_n}$$
with `\mathbb{Z}_n` which produces
$$\Huge\mathbb{Z}_n$$
There are no lowercase letters in the `\mathbb` font, and even if there were, it wouldn't change the fact that only the `Z` is supposed to be in the `\mathbb` font, while the `n` is supposed to look the way it normally does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the statement. It does not say that a set of generators is given by **all** elements prime to $n$. It says that **any** element prime to $n$ will generate the group. In particular, you are right that $\overline 1$ will be a generator. Note the $0$ is not prime to $n$ and $\overline 0$ is not a generator.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that the set $\{\overline{0},\overline{1}\}$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

However, *that's not what the question is about*. The issue is which elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ generate the entire group **on their own** -  in other words, for which integers $k$ does the set $\{\overline{k}\}\subset\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ generate all of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? The answer to that is "the integers $k$ that are relatively prime to $n$".

Answer (score 2):

The element $\overline{1}$ generates the group  $\mathbb Z_n$ but not the element $\overline{0}$.

Notice  that the element $\overline{k}$ generates the group $\mathbb Z_n$ if there's $p$ such that
$$p\overline{k}=\overline{1}\iff pk\equiv 1 \mod n\iff pk+qn=1\iff k\wedge n=1$$

Comment: Is $k\wedge n$ supposed to be a notation for the gcd of $k$ and $n$?

Comment: Yes it is and it is a commonly used notation.

Comment: Good to know...

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, $\overline0$ is never a generator ($0$ is not prime with $7$).
You are right that $\overline1$ is always a generator of $\mathbb Z_n$, as it is always prime with $n$.

You don't need $\overline0$, since you can reach it with $\overline1$ in this way: $\overline1+\overline1+\dots+\overline1$ (n times) $=\overline n=\overline 0$.

Comment: Yes I noticed that a little later. Thanks!